# How to correctly automatically bump version on config file on a new tag push?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm developing a Rust binary and in addition of the version field on `Cargo.toml`, I have also a nix flake file into the project that also define a version field. So I decided to bump these versions, via GitHub CI, when a new tag is pushed.

Then I implemented this workflow:

```yaml
name: Bump peadesafios version

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "v*.*.*"

env:
  REGEX: v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
  REGEX_CARGO: '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
  FLAKE: flake.nix
  CARGO: Cargo.toml
  BRANCH_NAME: auto-update/peadesafios-flake
  GIT_AUTHOR_NAME: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
  GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL: ${{ github.repository_owner }}@users.noreply.github.com
  PEADESAFIOS_VERSION: '' # init the var

jobs:
  bump-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./cli
        shell: bash

    steps:
      - name: Get the release version from the tag and old version
        shell: bash
        if: env.PEADESAFIOS_VERSION == ''
        run: |
          echo "PEADESAFIOS_VERSION=${GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "version is: ${{ PEADESAFIOS_VERSION }}"

      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: main
          fetch-depth: 1

      - name: Get old version
        run: |
          export version=$(grep -owE ${{ env.REGEX }} ${{ env.FLAKE }})
          echo "OLD_VERSION=$version" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Update version in flake.nix
        run: sed -i "s/$OLD_VERSION/$PEADESAFIOS_VERSION/g" ${{ env.FLAKE }}

      - name: Update version in Cargo.toml
        run: |
          export version=$(grep -owE ${{ env.REGEX_CARGO }} ${{ env.CARGO }})
          sed -i "s/$version/$PEADESAFIOS_VERSION/g" ${{ env.CARGO }}

      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v4
        with:
          commit-message: "update: flake package version"
          author: ${{ env.GIT_AUTHOR_NAME }} <${{ env.GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL }}>
          title: 'nixpacks-flake: ${{ env.OLD_VERSION }} -> ${{ env.PEADESAFIOS_VERSION }}'
          branch: ${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}
          signoff: true
          delete-branch: true
```

However GitHub gives me this error:

```bash
Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/bump-version.yaml#L30
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/bump-version.yaml (Line: 30, Col: 14): Unrecognized named-value: 'PEADESAFIOS_VERSION'. Located at position 1 within expression: PEADESAFIOS_VERSION
```

I admit that I didn't understand this error. I'm only echoing the value back to the `$GITHUB_ENV`, so what the problem of this workflow?

Comment: it seems that `env.PEADESAFIOS_VERSION` is getting a empty value from `GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/`

Comment: You can simply use [`github.ref_name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the GitHub Action docs on writing to `$GITHUB_ENV`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-of-writing-an-environment-variable-to-github_env), the `${{ PEADESAFIOS_VERSION }}` should be `${{ env.PEADESAFIOS_VERSION }}` instead. In `${{ ... }}`, you need to prepend it with the context, in this case `env.`, that the value `PEADESAFIOS_VERSION` exists in.

But also, you wont have access to variables appended to the `$GITHUB_ENV` scope until the next step. If you swap it to include `env.`, it will no longer error, but it will print an empty string, because the contents of the script to `run:` were already templated, *before* the line *in* the step adds the value to `$GITHUB_ENV`.

For example;

```yaml
name: Bump tag-ish version
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "v*.*.*"
jobs:
  bump-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
    steps:
      - name: Snip tag out of ref, save as TAGISH_VERSION
        run: |
          echo "TAGISH_VERSION=${GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          # These wont work right now
          echo "version is: ${{ env.TAGISH_VERSION }}"
          echo "version is, also: $TAGISH_VERSION"
      - name: Use TAGISH_VERSION
        run: |
          # They will work now it's the next step.
          echo "version is: ${{ env.TAGISH_VERSION }}"
          echo "version is, also: $TAGISH_VERSION"
          echo "But also, we have $GITHUB_REF_NAME to use."
```

Will yeild;

[image: screenshot of the results of running the above example on a tag push.]